# In Vagrant, how to populate provisioning env variable only when actually provisioning?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm setting up a Vagrantfile that needs to put a secret key onto the guest during provisioning.  The key is GPG encrypted, and I'd like to pass it in an environment variable to a provisioning script.  I've written a Ruby method (`get_secret_key`) that will decrypt it.  But using this in the `env` option of Vagrant's shell provisioner results in calling `get_secret_key` every time I run vagrant, not just when provisioning.

Calling `get_secret_key` may prompt for my passphrase, so I'd like to avoid calling it unnecessarily.  E.g., when running `vagrant ssh`.

Here's an abbreviated version of what I've got in my `Vagrantfile`:

```
def get_secret_key()
  # code that returns a string
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/buster64"
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    env: {"secret_key" => get_secret_key()},
    inline: "echo $secret_key > /tmp/secret_key"
end
```

As I mentioned, this pretty much works, but I'd like to call `get_secret_key` only when actually provisioning.